# upload to imgur with url, via url

Tags: reddit, imgur

You can share / post to facebook, twitter, and reddit via url. The shareable content can also be embedded in the url as well.

Can the same be done for imgur? You can upload content to imgur by just linking to it with a url. example: [how one would manually input a url to imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCmvr.png)

Comment: Try reading this you may find what you search for http://imgur.com/tools